# React Native FlatList Doesn't show anything

Tags: react-native

I'm making my first ever flatlist in react native:

```
<FlatList
        data ={this.state.courselist}
        renderItem={ this.item}
        keyExtractor={(item)=>item.title}
        >
          </FlatList>
```

this.state.courselist is defined so:

```
courselist:{
  progress:[],
  title:[]
},
```

and dynamically filled in using these functions:

```
async getdata(){
  var id = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("id");
  console.log(id)
  return fetch('http://192.168.2.128:4000/StuCurs/'+id)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    responseJson.forEach(element =>{
      console.log(element);
      this.getcoursedata(element.cursusId,element.progression)
      this.state.courselist.progress.push(
       Number( parseInt(element.progression)))
       console.log("ppp-"+this.state.courselist.progress[0])
       this.setState({ Render: "" });
      
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  
}
async getcoursedata(id,progress){
  return await fetch("http://192.168.2.128:4000/Cursuss/"+id)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJSON=>{
    
    console.log(responseJSON.naam)
    this.state.courselist.title.push(responseJSON.naam.toString())
    console.log(this.state.courselist.title[0])
    this.setState({ Render: "" });
  })
}
```

The list doesn't present anything. My best guess is that my courselist structure is wrong, I'm not sure how I restructure it to work as intented considering how I have to get my data from my database.

However, I made a test variable to test if I just could present any premade data:

```
 testarray:[
      {
        title:"wiskunde",
        progress:25
      },
      {
        title:'nederlands',
        progress:55
      }
    ],
```

If I attempt to use this array, the page won't load at all.
How do I fix my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the docs, you'll see that the `renderItem` prop needs to be passed a function that each item gets mapped to, which returns some JSX. This could be as simple as:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Text>{item.title} {item.progress}</Text>
```

Comment: I've added your code to my file, now my testarray functions properly, I still can't use the information from my database however, any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Well, one thing you should do is set your API data using setState rather than pushing it, so you don't need that extra setState to force a render